# Time in miliseconds in c++ in a for loop always same

Tags: c++, for-loop, time

I have a for loop like :

```
        ofstream myfile;
        myfile.open ("clnt.txt",std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
        struct timeval  tv;
        gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
                double time_in_mill1 = 
                 (tv.tv_sec) * 1000 + (tv.tv_usec) / 1000 ; 
                cout<<time_in_mill1<<endl;
                int n1=sprintf (den, "%lf",  time_in_mill1);
                printf ("[%s] is a string %d chars long\n",den,n1);
                myfile << den;
        }
```

and in the clnt.txt file all values are '-2090430839.000000' and on the screen '-2.09043e+09' is written for all time_in_mill1 values. I expected that at least two values are to be different. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're losing microsecond resolution by using integer division.  So if the loop completes in under a millisecond, all the logged times could be identical.  Or if `gettimeofday` on your system isn't very precise.  I suggest using `clock_gettime` instead.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to send packets from client to server and I need to measure time difference between sent packets I mean delay, if I use clock_gettime does it matter for measuring time difference in client and server?

Answer (score 2):

You need to move gettimeofday into the loop and to correct division

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    double time_in_mill1 = 
      (tv.tv_sec) * 1000 + (tv.tv_usec) / 1000.0 ; 
    ...
 }
```

Comment: I have changed my code now every value is '-2089269230.650000' . I think for loop is completed under 1 millisecond.

Comment: @user3246402 Most likely it is. You could insert Sleep function into loop to slow its execution. Or just write something like for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)

Answer (score 0):

I have just forgetting updating the gettimeofday(). Now every value is different from each other. Thanks for all answers.

```
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("clnt.txt",std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
struct timeval  tv;
gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);

    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
              gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
              double time_in_mill1 = 
              (tv.tv_sec) * 1000 + (tv.tv_usec) / 1000.0 ; 
              cout<<time_in_mill1<<endl;
              int n1=sprintf (den, "%lf",  time_in_mill1);
              printf ("[%s] is a string %d chars long\n",den,n1);
              myfile << den;
     }
```